# How to add a rederecting in mobile metamask browser?

Tags: web3js, metamask

I created a site using web3.ys with some features, without react and node. How can I make it so that when entering from a mobile device and when clicking on the button, the user is transferred to the mobile metamask and immediately opens the browser with my site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I use:

```js
export function connectMetaMask(chainId) {
  if (!window.ethereum && isMobile()) connectMetamaskMobile();
  else return metaMaskConnector.activate(chainId);
}

export const connectMetamaskMobile = () => {
  const dappUrl = window.location.href.split("//")[1].split("/")[0];
  const metamaskAppDeepLink = "https://metamask.app.link/dapp/" + dappUrl;
  window.open(metamaskAppDeepLink, "_self");
};
```

This is described in [the MetaMask Docs](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/mobile-best-practices.html#deeplinking).
I'm using this together with web3-react, however you only need the `connectMetaMaskMobile` part. Check [this out](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) if you want more info on detecting mobile browsers.

Comment: Im dont understund, how it integrate in my site:v

Comment: The code is not very complex, add in the function `connectMetaMaskMobile` somewhere and when a user clicks on a button, execute that function..

Comment: <button onclick="functionToExecute(connectMetaMaskMobile)">Click</button>
Right?

Comment: more like: <button onclick="connectMetaMaskMobile()">Click</button>. When using normal html with js, you also take out the 'export' keyword.

Comment: Thank u:) Sorry for my bad knowledges)

Comment: Bro, its not work, maybe need connect smth more? I have a script web3min.js and nothing else

Comment: This script has nothing to do with web3js. It simply opens up a deeplink that will open up MetaMask on a users mobile phone if they have it installed. Please read the docs.